# Delayed HTTP response causes session to expire

Tags: http, timeout, cgi, response

My site requires creation of PDF reports based on user's request. Upon a request (I've used GET), my CGI generates the PDF first, only then I send the response (along with the PDF) to the browser.

In case of large amount of data, PDF generation takes significant time and after few minutes of no response, the page expires.

I tried using the "Expires" HTTP response, but it didn't work.

The site may be deployed on IIS or Apache & is allowed to be viewed only on IE 7.0 or above.

Any help is appreciated.

PS.

Comment: as you didn't mention what webserver you are using or what platform you are using maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629566/how-to-increase-apache-timeout-directive-in-htaccess) helps...

Comment: Change your approach. Instead of sending the PDF as a response, write it to the file system. During generation, write every 30 seconds "please wait" back to the client, so the session won't time out. At the end, write the link to the generated PDF.

Comment: Dear Perleone, can you please give me some pointers on achieving this.