# Very long PHP operation: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php

I am reading 10,000 csv files each has 1000 rows and remove the duplicate and create new file

For that

1. I read line by line and store the data in a array.
2. When I store new data in the array, I check the weather it is not duplicate (weather the array already have the data)
3. Then recreate csv using array

Additionally I changed following in the php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 30000 
max_input_time = 60000 
memory_limit = -1 
error_log = error_log
```

But I am getting following error. There is no error log. Is there any other configuration to change in the php.ini. Please help me on it

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@xxxxxx.com and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: your probably hitting a limit in apache, it might be better to run something like this via the command line.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629566/how-to-increase-apache-timeout-directive-in-htaccess.  Also I would change these at runtime and not globally.

Comment: You should try to [generate some log output](https://davidwinter.me/enable-php-error-logging/) to see what's going on and perhaps some benchmarking as well. Did you check the Apache/webserver log? The other suggestions are also good options: use CLI and/or smaller batches. I would also see if whatever method you are using to check for dupes may be taking too much time and perhaps could be optimized. Also, are you using native php function (`str_getcsv`) or something else (may or may not help depending on your data)?

Comment: i changed Apache Timeout  to 30000 but  scrip is keep ringing . no output

Comment: I reduced the file to 1000 it workes

Comment: Just curious. You mentioned "no output." Does that mean you are trying to do all 10,000 csv files in memory instead of read -> process -> write 10,000 times?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from checking for the Apache Timeout, you should try to break this script once & try to run it in batches of probably 2000 csv files.
It is also possible that some data in one of the CSV files is causing this error, which would be identified if you break it in batches of 2000 files & run.

Answer (score 0):

500 error can give due to timeout. This can be happen from PHP and Apache2 configuration.

Suggested configuration for php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 30000 
max_input_time = 60000 
memory_limit = -1
```

Also, increase **TimeOut** in httpd.conf (in server config or vhost config).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).