# ftp_rawlist/ftp_nlist causes error500 randomly

Tags: php, ftp

I would like to crawl my FTP server using ftp_rawlist from my web server.

It do work, but not always.

My FTP server is hosted on a windows server 2016 using IIS.
It is a simple FTP account (Not FTPS and w/o certificate).

My PHP server runs PHP V7.2.30 hosted on 1and1.
the memory limit is set to 128M.

the code is as follow (I am using AJAX to query the page (POST method):

display.php

```
$ftp_server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$ftp_username = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$ftp_userpass = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to the FTP server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$scan = ftp_get_filelist($ftp_conn, '.');
var_dump($scan);
```

function.php

```
function ftp_get_filelist($ftp_conn, $path){
 $Win=false;
 $contents = ftp_rawlist ($ftp_conn, $path);
 $Output = array();
 $i = 0;

 foreach ($contents as $Current) {
  $Split = preg_split('[ ]', $Current, 9, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  if ($Split[0] != 'total') {
   $Output[$i]['isdir']     = ($Split[0] {0} === 'd');
   $Output[$i]['perms']     = $Split[0];
   $Output[$i]['number']    = $Split[1];
   $Output[$i]['owner']     = $Split[2];
   $Output[$i]['group']     = $Split[3];
   $Output[$i]['size']      = $Split[4];
   $Output[$i]['month']     = $Split[5];
   $Output[$i]['day']       = $Split[6];
   $Output[$i]['time']   = $Split[7];
   $Output[$i]['full_date'] = '2020-'.$Split[5].'-'.$Split[6].' '.$Split[7];
   $Output[$i]['name']      = $Split[8];
   $i++;
  }
 }
 return !empty($Output) ? $Output : FALSE;

}
```

All looks to work (but the year, I didn't succeed to get it yet but that is another problem).

So when I run it, ok I have the list of files and folder.
I refresh ok still working,
I refresh again, then its like loading and then the PHP server send an error:

Error 500 - Internal server error

Errors that happen 2 for 5 times are really hard for me to debug.

I tried to look in the log file, and I have found the requests with the error 500 code but not more info:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [08/May/2020:06:05:50 +0200] "POST display.php HTTP/1.1" 500 669 www.xxxxxx.com "https://xxxxxx.com/display.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

If someone have any idea, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: And why do you think it is caused by the `ftp_rawlist`? It seems that you have to debugging place. So how can you know?

Comment: I think it comes from ftp_rawlist because when I replace it with a ftp_nlist I have no issue. but ftp_nlist is not good for my need as it only list the files and not the folders

Comment: That seems unlikely, unless the problem is that your script reaches a memory limit (due to a larger output of `ftp_rawlist`) or a script execution limit.

Comment: wait let me re-confirm my previous statement.

Comment: So you were right, i did stress test more using the ftp_nlist and actually it is reacting the same at some point. the FTP folder that is crawled on have 1 text file and a folder.

Comment: So check the limits. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38195347/850848

Comment: Well looks like its not comming from the limit (and honestly, to list 1 file and 1 folder..). I tried to set all to high as advised but no changes

Answer (score 1):

So I am happy to tell you that I find how to solve the problem.
But to be honest I don't understand the nature of the problem...

The solution comes from that thread :
[PHP FTP ftp_nlist not working, returning boolean false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219322/php-ftp-ftp-nlist-not-working-returning-boolean-false)

just added after ftp_login() :

```
ftp_set_option($ftp_conn, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false); // set ftp option
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true); //make connection to passive mode
```

Thanks for your time @Martin

Comment: If `FTP_USEPASVADDRESS` or `ftp_pasv` were the only fix, I do not understand how your script could have ever worked. Anyway, at least it works now :)