# Php long script timeout with ajax call

Tags: php, json, ajax, apache, freebsd

I'm building a website for my office work which loads dynamically tables from an long PHP script. To do that, I've created a PHP file that handle AJAX and Get request (echo JSON from long PHP script).

When i use my code in local machine with a WAMP server all works good, of course I had to add this line `ini_set('max_execution_time', 5000);` to avoid the issue of timeout.

My problem is when i put my project on real Virtual Machine with FreeBSD environment that doesn't work, i mean after 600 sec the server kill my request (Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'HttpException' with message 'An error occurred : [503]).

But I note that if I run the PHP file directly from the console in command line all works good and the script echo my JSON request.

The detail of the script is essentially from `for each` and ended by echo JSON of processing loops.

So my question is how i can manage it ?

I was thinking about do something like that :

- call the file script.php from ajax in command line
- split the file script.php to avoid the timeout

Below, here is a scheme of the current process :
[image: process]

Comment: Is s user going to wait this long?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629566/how-to-increase-apache-timeout-directive-in-htaccess

Comment: @Dagon Yes the user will wait the final result because is a website for my office work.
@GauravSrivastava i already tried `max_execution_time` without success but i will test the other method for apache, thanks.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava well, i tried to add Timeout to the httpd.conf file but the result is the same :\