# I get 503 after copying to many files with PHP

Tags: php, file, copy, php-7.2, http-status-code-503

I am trying to duplicate an entire folder (a very big one) with a recursive function.

```
class Folder {
    static function copy (string $source, string $destination) {
        $dir = opendir($source);
        if (!is_dir($destination))
            mkdir($destination, 0755, true);

        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                if (is_dir($source .'/'. $file)) {
                    self::copy($source .'/'. $file, $destination .'/'. $file);
                }
                else {
                    copy($source .'/'. $file, $destination .'/'. $file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
}
```

This method copies only a part of the folders/files and after that it does nothing for a while (more than 30 seconds) and ends the process with a 503.

I don't know why it cant copy all of them. Are some of files to big for PHP?

**Edit:**

I found out the script can't pass over copying one of files with a size of 100M+.

How can I increase size of files that `copy` function can copy ?

**Edit:**

I even tried these settings which didn't help:

```
ini_set('memory_limit',         '-1');
ini_set('max_input_time',       '-1');
ini_set('max_input_vars',       '10000');
ini_set('max_execution_time',   5000);
ini_set('post_max_size',        '300M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize',  '300M');
```

Comment: 503 is server internal error. your problem is in your memory limitation or in your code. you can open show errors yo see what is problem. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
`ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: max_input_time = 3600 try setting this

Comment: @ttrasn errors are enabled. There is no error.
"503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" doesn't mean PHP error.

Comment: @ValentinTanasescu so see error_log file in your project directory.

Comment: I did that. There is no PHP error nowhere.

Comment: seems like a web server error, if you use apache, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629566/how-to-increase-apache-timeout-directive-in-htaccess

Comment: Thanks for reply @Jean-CharlesLUC. It's not about max_execution_time. It's about a filesize limit copy function allow.

Comment: How can make copy function allow also files with bigger size ?